# How does Solandra store documents?

Tags: pointers, lucene, solr, indexing, cassandra

Does Solandra store documents as-they-are (in rows of a column family, for example), with the Lucene index containing only pointer information... or are documents bound into (stored with) the index itself (which, of course, is stored in Cassandra)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark a document field stored=true then the document is stored as is in the Docs ColumnFamily.  The key however is essentially random so there is no way to look it up unless you know the internal solandra id.

Comment: Is there a way to get a hold of this Solandra id? Would I have to get a hold of this ID during the write to the index - I'm assuming this would slow down things.

Answer (score 1):

From http://blog.sematext.com/2010/02/09/lucandra-a-cassandra-based-lucene-backend/:

```
Document Key                Column Key  Value
"indexName/documentId" => { fieldName , value }
```